# "ImportError: No module named" error after upgrading pip to 7.10

Tags: python, django, django-admin, migration, pip

The last time that I was trying to install a Django package by Pip, it showed me that the last version of Pip is available! but, when I upgraded it I encountered with an error like below:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 522, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg' -> '/tmp/pip-vmqzjiuv-uninstall/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 532, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 463, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 401, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 421, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 419, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'cmdoptions.py'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/alireza/.pip/pip.log
```

And after that, when I install each Django package and run `python manage.py makemigrations` I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2201, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'tagging'
```

What should I do? I'm newbie, and using Django 1.8

Comment: You are getting a permission denied error, what is the exact command you are you running? Obviously if you are trying to install globally you will need to run pip with sudo

Comment: I install now all my package with sudo unlike previous, but now I am running `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: I imagine you need `sudo python manage.py makemigrations` or to use a virtualenv

Comment: I used sudo `python manage.py makemigrations` , but a new error: `ImportError: cannot import name parse_lookup`

Comment: Do you have a few different versions of python3.4  installed? You seem to have `/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` in your output

Comment: I checked! yes! I think so. What should I do? tnx

Comment: add the output of `which -a pip` and `which -a python3`

Comment: Aso did `python manage.py makemigrations` work before you upgraded pip?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! excuse me, where should I add which -a pip and python3?

Comment: from bash or whatever shell you use, then add the output here, when you installed with pip do you use pip or pip3?

Comment: I used `pip install --upgrade pip`, `/home/alireza/test/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3`, `/usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Previously did you always use sudo pip or just pip to install packages?

Comment: Did you really get `/usr/local/bin/pip` twice in the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83806/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-altruistic).